# Problema con identificador

Tags: c

tengo un inconveniente puesto que necesito crear unas estructuras, pero estas me dan un problema de de identificador, que es este: **el identificador "musica" no está definidoC/C++(20)**, lo que quiero lograr es hacer una lista enlazada (apenas estoy aprendiendo), aun utilizando un typedef esto me da error diciendo que no existe identificador para esta palabra, entonces no se que podria ser, si es algun problema de libreria y de ser asi, como puedo componerlas.

Adjunto codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct musica {
    char nombre[15];
    float duracion;
};

struct Nodo {
    musica lista;
    Nodo *siguente;
};
```

En teoria esto esta correcto, deberia de funcionar, pero me da el error antes mencionado, si no logro resolver esto, no puedo seguir adelante con el programa, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En C, cuando creas un nuevo tipo de dato con `struct`, al **declarar** la variable con el nuevo tipo de dato necesitas anteponer la palabra clave `struct`:

```c
struct musica 
{
    char nombre[15];
    float duracion;
};

musica musica1; //Error.
struct musica musica2; //No hay error.
```

Sin embargo, para evitar repetir la palabra clave `struct` en cada declaración, podríamos usar `typedef`, que sirve para crear un alias a un tipo de dato. Es decir, al tipo `struct musica`, le creamos un **alias** que sea solo `musica` (sin el `struct`), en código sería así:

```c
//Declaramos la estructura y a la vez creamos el "alias".
typedef struct musica musica;

struct musica 
{
    char nombre[15];
    float duracion;
};

musica musica2; //No hay error.
```

Entonces, para corregir tu código, simplemente crea el alias del tipo antes de la definición de la estructura:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Nodo Nodo; //Crea el alias "Nodo"
typedef struct musica musica; //Crea el alias "musica"

struct musica {
    char nombre[15];
    float duracion;
};

struct Nodo {
    musica lista; //"musica" es el alias de "struct musica"
    Nodo *siguente;//"Nodo" es el alias de "struct Nodo"
};
```

Por supuesto, también se puede crear el alias al momento de definir la estructura:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char nombre[15];
    float duracion;
}musica;

typedef struct {
    musica lista;
    Nodo *siguente;
}Nodo;
```

Pero.... sigue dando un error:

```
error: unknown type name 'Nodo'
```

La estructura es `Nodo` pero dentro de su definición, estamos declarando una variable de tipo `Nodo`, por lo que necesitamos anteponer la palabra clave `struct`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char nombre[15];
    float duracion;
}musica;

typedef struct {
    musica lista;
    struct Nodo *siguente;
}Nodo;
```

Y listo... **usa la solución que mas te guste.**

Answer (score 3):

Lo que sucede es que en C hay que usar la palabra clave `struct` cada vez que se quiere crear una variable cuyo tipo es una estructura:

```
struct musica {
    char nombre[15];
    float duracion;
};

struct Nodo {
    struct musica lista;
    struct Nodo *siguente;  /* Nota: aca dice struct Nodo */
};
```

Otra alternativa es usar `typedef` para definir un nuevo tipo de datos, que no requiera especificar `struct` cada vez:

```
typedef struct musica {
    char nombre[15];
    float duracion;
} musica;

typedef struct Nodo {
    struct musica lista;
    struct Nodo *siguente;
} Nodo;
```

Saludos.